# ASP.net Identity reset password without a reset token

Tags: asp.net

I want to use asp.net Identity reset password without a reset token. Just enter username and new password. Is this possible? I am using webforms.

Comment: So... You want any user to be able to set the password for any other user any time they want?

Comment: Yes.  I need the password reset to be simple so I dont want to use the email and token

Comment: I think you're missing the point... If every user can control every other user's password then why bother having a password at all?  The approach you describe entirely removes the purpose of having one.  While it's certainly not recommended, if that's your intent then just let people login with nothing but a username.  More to the point of the question though... Since what you describe is *completely insecure* then, no, there's probably no built-in functionality to support it.

Comment: That makes sense.   My issue is that I am migrating usernames and password from another table and dont have email addresses.  I think that I will not be able to do the migration and make them create a new account.